# Can I use the Softmax function with a binary classification in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I want to create a deep learning model (CNN) for binary classification, can I used the softmax function instead of the sigmoid function in binary classification?

Adding the classification layer to the model, will be like this

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For binary classification, it should give the same results, because softmax is a generalization of sigmoid for a larger number of classes.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is not **always** a yes. You can always formulate the binary classification problem in such a way that both sigmoid and softmax will work. **However you should be careful to use the right formulation.**

**Sigmoid** can be used when your last dense layer has **a single neuron** and outputs a single number which is a score. Sigmoid then maps that score to the range **[0,1]**. You can then assume that this is a probability distribution and say that the prediction is *class* 1 if the probability is larger than *0.5* and *class 0* other wise.

If you want to use **softmax**, you need to adjust your last dense layer such that it has **two neurons**. It must output two numbers which corresponds to the scores of each class, namely *0* and *1*. Now, you can use softmax to convert those scores into a probability distribution. Finally, to get the predicted label, you still need to find the `argmax` in the probability distribution.

**You can **not** use **softmax** when you have a single neuron in the last layer.** This will lead to some strange behaviour and performance will drop. **Obviously, you can also not use sigmoid when you formulate the problem with two dimensional last layer.**

So it is either

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

or

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```